# What is the difference between coreference resolution and anaphora resolution?

Tags: terminology, discourse-analysis, anaphora

Is there any difference between coreference resolution and anaphora resolution? More generally, what is the difference between coreferences and anaphoras?

Comment: Can you give us an example? The anaphor and its antecedent are cofreferents. One succinct way to state it is, coreference is the relationship that binds the functions of two words. Anaphor binds the meaning of another word.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Tim Osborne is very comprehensive and accurate. But perhaps things might be easier when looked at through usage in text linguistics.

Although, co-reference and anaphora can be distinct, they are often used interchangeably by linguists. This is partly because by far the most studied type of anaphoric reference is co-referential.  So you could say that co-reference is one of the processes through which anaphora is encoded. It is not just a type of anaphora because co-reference can also be cataphoric (although some people use anaphora to mean reference in both directions).

So the difference between anaphora and correference resolution follows from the above.

Answer (score 6):

An obvious difference I see (or, rather, one Ruth Kempson saw in a 1977 textbook of hers), especially from a cross-theoretical perspective (i.e., leaving terminological issues aside as much as possible), is that 'anaphora' is an intra-linguistically determinable relation, whereas 'co-reference' necessarily requires access to 'extra-linguistic' information. By definition, *co-reference* **always** implies 'identity of reference', whereas *anaphora* does **not** (I ignore here how the term *anaphor* - not *anaphora* - is used in Principle A of Chomsky's Binding Theory). In other words, the **relation** called *anaphora* may (but need not) hold of expressions that are supposed to have the same 'sense' (either in themselves, or only via context-dependent synonymy) but may still have **different referents** (and usually do), whereas co-reference does not depend on 'identity of sense' at all, but, of course, does strictly require co-referential terms to refer to the same extra-linguistic entity. This is most obvious, perhaps, in the use of **one** in *John has a BMW and his girlfriend has **one**, too*, where two different BMW's are being referred to, although similar examples can be built with all the other pro-forms (i.e., *so, do, do so, that/those, mine, yours*, etc., cf. *John finished his thesis in 1990 and Bill **did so** a year later*, *Your thesis is better than **mine***, etc.). On the contrary, co-referential terms, of course, may (but, again, need not) have completely different 'senses', and yet, by definition, they **must** refer to the same extralinguistic entity. Thus, in *My wife is sad because she misses her father*, *My wife* and *she* have different 'senses', but may still have the same 'referent' (and that's how the sentence is interpreted by default, in the absence of further context); on the contrary, in *She is sad because she misses her father*, both tokens of *she* cannot but have the same 'sense', but they still may (or may not) be co-referential, although, in the absence of further context, they will be interpreted as co-referential; in *John lost his temper*, finally, *John* and *his* **must** be co-referential. In view of that, you may expect huge differences in the resources and computational strategies respectively needed to identify 'anaphoric' and 'co-referential' expressions; typically, determining whether co-reference, an extra-linguistically determined property, holds or not between any two expressions will require much more 'pragmatic' information ('knowledge of the world') than identifying pairs of expressions in the strictly **intra-linguistic** relation of 'anaphora'.

Comment: "On the contrary, co-referential terms, ... by definition, they must refer to the same extralinguistic entity." What definition is that?  (There is no such agreed on definition.) And taking definite pronominalization to require coreference, there are counterexamples.  "He wants to catch a fish and eat it."  "He dreamt he caught a fish and ate it." "He didn't catch a fish or eat it."  "No one wore his own hat." "The alligator lost its tail but quickly regrew it" (after an example from Paul Postal).

Comment: Your answers would be more comprehensible if they were divided into coherent paragraphs. This sort of answer overwhelms many readers.

Comment: I said my answer was intended to be as theory-neutral as possible and was assuming that 'reference' (the 'semantic' relation between expressions and their extralinguistic correlates), and consequently 'co-reference', were cross-linguistically accepted terms. If, in your favourite theory, 'reference' is not that kind of relation, of course, we would have to discuss your theory. My purpose was just to offer the OP a broadly accepted view, not to discuss problems of reference.

Comment: I'm sorry, Tim Osborne, you are right. I do not think my single paragraph answer is in any way 'incoherent', but I agree that avoiding such long Ciceronian paragraphs would make my answers more readable. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

The question is difficult to answer due to its brevity and the lack of context in which the terms *coreference* and *anaphora* appear. However, I can provide some orientation that should help increase understanding of how these terms are used.

The term *coreference* denotes a situation where two or more expressions refer to the same one entity in the world of discourse. In a situation where a speaker says

> (1) Look at that man over there; he is wearing a funny hat.

the phrase *that man* refers to the actual man in the discourse situation of the speaker, and the pronoun *he* refers to the phrase *that man* (its antecedent), so it too refers to the actual man in the discourse situation, although indirectly. Thus the two expressions, *that man* and *he*, are coreferential; they refer to the same one entity in the discourse situation.

Words or phrases that point to other words or phrases are anaphors. The term *anaphora* denotes the actual act of pointing (*anaphora* is technically already plural, so *anaphoras* is incorrect). Any time a given expression (word, phrase, or some combination of words) points to some linguistic expression (its antecedent), it is an anaphor (or cataphor). Pronouns are typical anaphors, but many other types of expressions can also be construed as anaphors, e.g. verbal expressions (*do so*, *do it*), adverbs (*there*), preposition-like combinations (*thereof*, *therefore*), etc. Any time one of these expressions occurs in speech or writing, anaphora is present. The anaphor is pointing to some expression in the linguistic or situational context.

The main point of confusion that arises in this area concerns the presence of anaphora without coreference. Consider the following sentence in this regard:

> (2) No man said he was hungry.

Anaphora is present in this sentence, since the pronoun *he*, an anaphor, is pointing back at its antecedent *no man*. But the antecedent *no man* does not pick out an actual entity in the discourse world. The expression *no man* cannot be construed as referring to anything at all. What this means is that coreference is not present, but anaphora is.

When one spends some time probing these distinctions, one quickly sees that the terminology is not clear, and often the terms are used inconsistely or unclearly. But that is understandable, since the notions at play are rather fuzzy, even for many seasoned linguists.

An appeal to caution: the term *anaphor* has a special meaning in Government and Binding Theory (GB) and the Minimalist Program (MP). These frameworks of syntax use the term *anaphor* to denote what most of linguistics in general calls a reflexive pronoun (or a reciprocal pronoun). Thus in GB/MP, words like *himself*, *herself*, *themselves*, *itself*, *each other*, etc. are called anaphors. The study of syntax and grammar in general uses the term *anaphor* (and *cataphor*) more broadly, to denote any expression that points to some other linguistic unit or entity in discourse.

The Wikipedia articles on [anaphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28linguistics%29), [coreference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference), and [binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_%28linguistics%29) can help build understanding about these issues.

Finally, I'm not sure what is meant by "coreference resolution" and "anaphora resolution". I assume those terms are meant to denote situations in which an anaphor successfully finds its antecedent (or postcedent) in context. Anaphora resolution would, then, fail to occur if a given pronoun appears for which it is not clear what its antecedent or postcedent is supposed to be, e.g. *Fred and Tom said he was hungry*. Does *he* refer to *Fred*, *Tom*, or to someone else entirely.

Comment: You say there is no coreference in "No man said he was hungry".  Yet in the predicate logic form for this example, there is coreference between the subject arguments of "say" and "be hungry", which happen both to be in the scope of the same negation.  This suggests your notion of "discourse world" is too limited.

Comment: @GregLee: I guess that's why Tim said there is *anaphora* in (2). The pronoun *he* is bound by the subject *no man*, but when there's no **reference**, there's no **coreference** either. Predicate logic doesn't have problems with this.

Comment: No, @IvanKapitonov, the pronoun *he* is not bound by *no man*, because *no man* is not the logical subject of *say*.  The surface forms are misleading, here, because negation has scope over the entire rest of the clause: *not(some man said he was hungry)*, and the antecedent of *he* is the implicit *some man*.

Comment: @GregLee So do you suggest that there is an implicit *some man* with a specific refence, and the whole thing denies that he said he was hungry? Or am I missing some point?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, yes, with minor changes to your wording. "Some man" does not have a specific reference, and the whole thing denies that such a person said he was hungry.  (The "some" has to kept within the scope of negation, and *specific* means that a "some" is not within any significant scope.)

Comment: Alright, but I still don't see why give up compositionality in favour of some unwarranted tranformation. The narrow scope existential is straightforwardly obtained from the words *present* in the sentence, and not from implicit *not(some man)*.

Comment: @Greg Lee, formal semantic theory has been distinguishing between referring NPs and quantified NPs for decades.  Quantified NPs do not refer, e.g. "every woman", "some man", "no kids", etc. The pronoun in sentence (2) is a bound variable, as opposed to a referential NP. The distinction goes back at least as far as Partee (1970).

Comment: @TimOsborne, yes, *he* corresponds to a bound variable, and it is that variable which represents the coreferential the subject arguments of "say" and "be hungry".  Isn't that how you represent coreference -- same variable letter in the same quantifier scope.  How about the positive conterpart: "Some man said he was hungry."  Aren't "some man" and "he" coreferential, and isn't "some man" a quantified NP?  Your point escapes me here.

Comment: @Greg Lee, no, at least not according to established semantic theory -- not that I am a fan of established semantic theory. Semantic theory views quantified NPs as non-referential. The relevant distinction is between coreference and coindexation. Conindexation encompasses both coreference and bound variables.

Comment: @TimOsborne, So for example in "Some man left", since "some man" is a quantified NP, established semantic theory says that "some man" is non-referential?  I thought I knew something about semantic theory, but this is all news to me.  Please do tell us about when this semantic theory became established.

Comment: @Greg Lee, that's the problem, you know less than you think you do. Try Partee (1970) or Reinhart (1983: 164ff.). If you send me an email, I'll scan the pages and send them to you (tjo3ya@yahoo). Oh, I forgot, your email is not working. Too bad!

Answer (score 2):

Coreference anaphora is just one type of anaphora.  Following George Lakoff, syntacticians distinguish between identity-of-reference anaphora (which includes definite pronominalization) and identity-of-sense anaphora (which includes indefinite anaphora with "one").  So as a first approximation, the answer to the question is that anaphora includes indefinite anaphora, or that is to say, identity-of-sense anaphora, as well as coreferential anaphora.

For instance, in "He ate a green apple, but I ate a red one", in interpretation, "one" means "apple", but it is the meanings that are the same between antecedent ("apple") and pro-form ("one"), not the individuals.  He and I did not eat the same apple.

Comment: So in the example "He ate a green apple, but I ate a red one", the relationship between apple and one isn't' co-referential, Is it?